# Why does the inliner choke on this construct?

Tags: haskell, recursion, clash

I am trying to share as much code as possible between emulators and a CLaSH implementations for CPUs. As part of this, I am writing instruction fetching & decoding as something along the lines of

```
fetchInstr :: (Monad m) => m Word8 -> m Instr
```

This is trivial to run in the emulator using a monad that has a program counter in its state and direct access to memory. For the hardware version, I make a fixed-size buffer (since the instruction byte-length is bounded) and in every cycle, short-circuit the fetching if there is not enough data in the buffer yet.

```
data Failure
    = Underrun
    | Overrun
    deriving Show

data Buffer n dat = Buffer
    { bufferContents :: Vec n dat
    , bufferNext :: Index (1 + n)
    }
    deriving (Show, Generic, Undefined)

instance (KnownNat n, Default dat) => Default (Buffer n dat) where
    def = Buffer (pure def) 0

remember :: (KnownNat n) => Buffer n dat -> dat -> Buffer n dat
remember Buffer{..} x = Buffer
    { bufferContents = replace bufferNext x bufferContents
    , bufferNext = bufferNext + 1
    }

newtype FetchM n dat m a = FetchM{ unFetchM :: ReaderT (Buffer n dat) (StateT (Index (1 + n)) (ExceptT Failure m)) a }
    deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

runFetchM :: (Monad m, KnownNat n) => Buffer n dat -> FetchM n dat m a -> m (Either Failure a)
runFetchM buf act = runExceptT $ evalStateT (runReaderT (unFetchM act) buf) 0

fetch :: (Monad m, KnownNat n) => FetchM n dat m dat
fetch = do
    Buffer{..} <- FetchM ask
    idx <- FetchM get
    when (idx == maxBound) overrun
    when (idx >= bufferNext) underrun
    FetchM $ modify (+ 1)
    return $ bufferContents !! idx
  where
    overrun = FetchM . lift . lift . throwE $ Overrun
    underrun = FetchM . lift . lift . throwE $ Underrun
```

The idea is that this would be used by storing a `Buffer n dat` in the CPU's state during instruction fetching, and `remember`ing values coming in from memory while there is a buffer underrun:

```
case cpuState of
 Fetching buf -> do
            buf' <- remember buf <$> do
                modify $ \s -> s{ pc = succ pc }
                return cpuInMem
            instr_ <- runFetchM buf' $ fetchInstr fetch
            instr <- case instr_ of
                Left Underrun -> goto (Fetching buf') >> abort
                Left Overrun -> errorX "Overrun"
                Right instr -> return instr
            goto $ Fetching def
            exec instr
```

This works just fine in the CLaSH simulator.

The problem is, if I start using it this way, it needs a lot bigger inlining limit for CLaSH to be able to synthesize it. For example, on a CHIP-8 implementation, [this commit](https://github.com/gergoerdi/chip8-clash/commit/9ca30e40e2b7798f294b8507402f85eb46ad7228) starts using the above-described `FetchM`. Before this change, an inlining depth of just 100 is enough to get through the CLaSH synthesizer; after this change, 300 is not enough and 1000 causes CLaSH to just churn until it runs out of memory.

What is so evil about `FetchM` that the inliner chokes on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the real culprit was not `FetchM`, but other parts of my code that required inlining of a lot of functions (one per each monadic bind in my main `CPU` monad!), and `FetchM` just increased the number of binds.

The real problem was that my [`CPU` monad was, among other things, a `Writer (Endo CPUOut)`](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-utils/blob/cdc38b8e50e36474e7725775b456336474024515/src-clash/Cactus/Clash/CPU.hs#L12), and all those `CPUOut -> CPUOut` functions needed to be fully inlined since CLaSH can't represent functions as signals.

All of this is explained in more detail in [the related CLaSH bug ticket](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/613).